# Values of the PDF function get extremely high

Tags: probability

I have this histogram.

[image: Histogram]

I would like to approach this histogram to a PDF normal function. Therefore, I used the pdf function:

mu=1.056e-6

sigma=0.048e-6

pdf=(1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/).^2)

plot(x,pdf)

The plot is the following:

[image: Pdf plot]

Obviously, this output is not correct.

Am i doing anything wrong? Should I be dividing the output for some coefficient?

Thank you for your time,

João

Comment: Why is it incorrent? Scaling on x-axis is $10^{-7}$, on y-axis  - $10^6$ so the integral works out to order of $1$ from visual inspection - as expected.

Comment: You would like to find a normal distribution which can fit in this empirical distribution. But you cannot find one. You can try to compute the excess kurtosis of this distribution, and you should find that it is a leptokurtic distribution, which is expected as you said it has a very high peak. So normal distribution does not fit well.